# Disabling script execution on Apache2

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, php, apache-2.2

On a ubuntu-10.04 and Apache2 I am trying to disable PHP execution on */var/www/upload* directory. So I've added the following to */etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default*:

> < Directory /var/www/upload/> AddType text/plain .php < /Directory>

Then of course I've restarted the Apache2 service.

However, according to my tests, PHP is still being executed on the upload directory.

Anyone knows what I'm missing here?

Comment: What happens if you `chmod -R a-x /var/www/upload/*` ? (Remove execute permission on all files in `/var/www/upload` ?

Comment: Yes that's a solution :) , but I'd like to do that from Apache configuration. I've been fighting with this for a couple of hours and still nothing :/

Comment: Are you a sysadmin or is this site a home computer?

Comment: It's a Virtual Machine I'm testing on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the apache directive 'RemoveHandler' in directory context,

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#removehandler